# Cant understand the number of iteration in linear regression (Machine Learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I've been trying to get my head around machine learning over few days. I am watching Videos and articles all over the internet.
In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdM6ER7zTLk) video. Siraj(guy on the video) taught to create gradient descent from scratch with numpy and python. Here is the code:-

```
import numpy as np

ERROR = []

def compute_error_for_given_points(b, m, points):
    total_error = 0.0

    for i in range(0,len(points)):
        x = points[i,0]
        y = points[i,1]
        total_error += (y-(m * x + b))**2

    return total_error/float(len(points))

def step_gradient(b_current, m_current, points, learning_rate):
    b_gradient = 0
    m_gradient = 0
    N = float(len(points))

    for i in range(0,int(N)):
        x = points[i, 0]
        y = points[i, 1]
        b_gradient += -(2/N) * (y- (m_current*x + b_current))
        m_gradient += -(2/N) * x * (y- (m_current*x + b_current))
    new_b = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
    new_m = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)

    return new_b,new_m

def gradient_descent_runner(points,starting_b,starting_m,learning_rate,num_iteration):
    b = starting_b
    m = starting_m

    for i in range(num_iteration):
        ERROR.append(compute_error_for_given_points(b,m,points))
        b, m  = step_gradient(b, m, points, learning_rate)

    return b,m


def run():
    points = np.genfromtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',')
    #print(type(points))
    #print(points)
    #hyperparameter
    learning_rate = 0.0001

    #y = mx + b
    initial_b = 0
    initial_m = 0
    num_iteration = 100000

    b,m = gradient_descent_runner(points,initial_b,initial_m,learning_rate,num_iteration)
    print("OPTIMIZED: ",b)
    print("OPTIMIZED: ",m)
    print("Error: ",compute_error_for_given_points(b,m,points))
    print("\n")
    #print(ERROR)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I understand all the math and calculus stuff. But i cant get the idea of the variable *num_iteration*. He told to use 1000, got some values for **b** and **m**. But when im using higher than 1000, im getting differnt values of **b** and **m**. And the loop where *num_iteration* is used, cant we replace it with a while loop, condition would be until and unless we are getting the lowest value for cost function? So, if you people can please give me some insight in this *num_iteration* variable that would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the reason you use `for` and not `while` loop is since you might not get to the condition in the while loop if your data isn't linear, and then you will be in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For putting a condition on the while loop saying 'go till the lowest value of the cost function', you first have to know what that value would be. You won't know what that would be until the program finishes converging. There is no way you can know it beforehand.

So instead you make it run for an arbitrary number, in your case, 1000, and hope that by that many iterations, the least value of the cost(or at least a sensible value) would reach.

**EDIT**

This is what I am getting after running the code for 10000

```
OPTIMIZED:  4.247984440219189
OPTIMIZED:  1.3959992655297515
Error:  110.7863192974508
```

For 1000 -

```
OPTIMIZED:  0.08893651993741346
OPTIMIZED:  1.4777440851894448
Error:  112.61481011613473
```

When the code is run 1000 times, the error is more compared to what we get with 100000 times. This is as expected. The more you run the loop, the more parameters get closer to the optimum. With 100000 epochs, the code will keep adjusting b and m until an error or 110 is reached. With 1000, it will keep doing the same thing but it stops once it reaches 1000.

Comment: I changed the value to 100000 a different value of m and b is coming is it overshooting the minimum? But point to be noted the cost function values is coming less than value coming for 1000..

Comment: Why do you think that m and b is overshooting the minimum? As you said, the cost function for 100000 is less than that is for 1000. That's what we expect. If we run the code for 100 times more, we expect the cost to reduce. The more you run, the less we expect our cost function to get.

Comment: then if we keep on increasing the epochs...will we overfit the model?

Comment: Over-fitting is a slightly thing. If we keep on increasing the epochs, we expect the error of the training data to always decrease. That's what's happening here. Over-fitting comes in when we start talking about validation data. The more we run, the less error of the training data we will get. But that doesn't mean that the same will happen for validation data. With too many epochs, we can over-fit on the validation set and error might increase with the number of epochs.